# if space is present in txt file then goto next line in python, How do I do it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 def DNA_no():
   mappings = {"A":"1","T":"2","C":"3","G":"4"}
   result = []
   DNAseq = open("mytype.txt","r")
   DNA_seq = DNAseq.read()
   print(DNA_seq)

   print(len(DNA_seq))

   for current in DNA_seq:
       result += mappings[current]
       return result
```

I want to map the data files into numbers. It is working with the small input sequences but not with the reading text files. The error I having is that it may be spaces in txt file. I don't know how to read all and convert it.

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

Read all lines in an (`DNAseq`) array (of text lines) first.

```
fname ="mytype.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    DNAseq = f.readlines()

for seq in DNAseq:
    # remap code here
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    dseq()
  File "C:/Users/BRAHMA/Desktop/MEMS/working/hope.py", line 9, in dseq
    result += mappings[seq]
KeyError: 'GTCCAACGCCTCTCCCGGCCGCGGCCGCGCAGAAAAAAATTTTTGCCTGACGTGCCTTCAATGCACTGCT\n

Comment: Remove last char ('\n') from the line.   seq = seq[:-1]

Comment: mytype.txt file have a spaces in between before going to the nextline. Therefore, I'm not able to goto the next line.

Comment: Have you tried seq = re.sub(r' ',r'', seq) or seq = seq.replace(' ','') ? ( import re )